# How to add directive in make file in c++

Tags: c++, makefile

Is this the correct way of defining GLES_VERSION ?? I m getting #error in my program

c++ code

```
#if GLES_VERSION == 2
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#elif GLES_VERSION == 3
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
#else 
#error "GLES_VERSION must be defined as either 2 or 3" 
#endif
```

i m ending up here in #error

make file code

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJS =      hello.o

LIBS = -lX11 -lXau -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lm

GLES_VERSION = -D2 #is this correct ? 

TARGET =    hello \

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(GLES_VERSION) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be,

```
GLES_VERSION = -DGLES_VERSION=2
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
GLES_VERSION = -DGLES_VERSION=2
```

Comment: Although the customary approach would be to add it to the `CPPFLAGS` (which are the _preprocessing_ flags) and reuse